# first-order predicate calculus logic

Tags: logic

> Selling a book changes who owns it but not who wrote it

How do I represent the above statement in the form of first-order predicate calculus?
Does my attempt below makes any sense?

> Selling(x) -> ((owner(x)->owner(y)) ^¬(author(x)->author(y)))

Comment: If I reverse what you have done, i.e. translate from the predicate logic into English, I get: `If a book has been sold then (firstly) if the owner is x then the owner is y and (secondly) it is not true that if the author is x then the author is y.` Not really what you hoped for.

Comment: Since the sentence involves attributes whose values change from one point in time to another, the predicate logic representation will have to include a time parameter. e.g. owner(x,p,t) might represent the claim that book x was owned by person p at time t.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
∀b,o,a.(book(b)∧owner(b,o)∧author(b,a))→(selling(b)→(changes(o)∧¬changes(a)))
```

Where the signature contains the predicates book, owner, author, selling, and changes, with the respective (hopefully obvious) semantics. I do not think that you need a notion of time; you can give the formula the intended interpretation by choice of a suitable structure/model for it.